# ComboBox SelectChangeCommited fires off with first keyboard input

Tags: vb.net, events, combobox, event-handling, mouseevent

I have a ComboBox. My issue is when I click on element 1, then start typing the name of a element 2, the first letter of my element 2 gets added. This only happens on the key down after a click event.

---

Process:

1. Click on ComboBox
2. Type in a name
3. Click on the elements name - element gets added to my grid
4. Type in another name - *ISSUE* - first element that matches the first letter I input gets added to the grid

Clicking and the enter key on a single selected element works fine.

My AutoCompleteMode is set to Append and AutoCompleteSource is ListItems

---

The solution I thought to control a click is in my `SelectionChangeComitted` function. If I can control the flag `isCLick` to only be set true when we know that a **element from the combo box** is clicked by the mouse. `MouseClick` will return true if the user clicks on the overall ComboBox therefore will always be true if we're dealing with this particular ComboBox. Since the parameter is `EventArgs` I cannot directly cast it to `MouseEventArgs`, would be great if I could.

---

**To sum up what my problem is:** I need to replace `isClick` boolean in my `SelectionChangeCommitted` to validate if the `SelectionChangeCommitted` was triggered by a click or not.

Is that possible in this case? Would there be any alternatives to bypass this issue?

I have event handler code below, the sequence of the call is: MouseClick -> PreviewKeyDown -> SelectionChangeCommitted -> SelectedValueChanged

http://pastebin.com/9zWGHbWE

```
AddHandler CType(ctl, ComboBox).PreviewKeyDown, Sub(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
                                                                If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Up OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Right OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
                                                                    e.IsInputKey = False
                                                                    AddToGrid = False
                                                                    isArrowKey = True
                                                                    isClick = False
                                                                ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
                                                                    AddToGrid = True
                                                                    isArrowKey = False
                                                                    isClick = False
                                                                    'Check if row already exists before insert a new one.
                                                                    If Not RowExists(DirectCast(ctl, Control).Tag, DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox).Text.ToUpper()) Then AppendGrid(sender)

                                                                Else
                                                                    AddToGrid = False
                                                                    isArrowKey = False
                                                                    isClick = True
                                                                End If
                                                            End Sub

            AddHandler CType(ctl, ComboBox).SelectedValueChanged, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                                                      'MessageBox.Show("SelectionValueChanged")
                                                                      If CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedValue Is Nothing Then Return
                                                                      If Not AddToGrid Then Return

                                                                      'Check if row already exists before insert a new one.
                                                                      If Not RowExists(DirectCast(ctl, Control).Tag, DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString().ToUpper()) Then
                                                                          AppendGrid(sender)
                                                                      End If
                                                                  End Sub

            AddHandler CType(ctl, ComboBox).SelectionChangeCommitted, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                                                          'MessageBox.Show("SelectionChangedCommitted")


                                                                          If CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedValue Is Nothing Then Return
                                                                          If isArrowKey Then Return 'if an arrow was used, then don't add it to the grid

                                                                          If isClick Then
                                                                              AddToGrid = True
                                                                          End If

                                                                          'Check if row already exists before insert a new one.
                                                                          If Not RowExists(DirectCast(ctl, Control).Tag, DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString().ToUpper()) AndAlso AddToGrid Then
                                                                              AppendGrid(sender)

                                                                          End If


                                                                      End Sub

            AddHandler CType(ctl, ComboBox).MouseClick, Sub(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
                                                            'MessageBox.Show("MouseClick")
                                                            isClick = True
                                                            AddToGrid = True
                                                        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like everything here works fine for you except when a click is executed. I would recommend you to reset the click after you use it. Try the code below in your SelectionChangeCommitted.

```
If isClick Then
    AddToGrid = True
    isClick = false
End If
```